# Is there a distance algorithm similar to Jaccard distance that handles scalar data?

Tags: similarities, distance-functions, jaccard-similarity

we have the characteristics and (scalar) values of those characteristics for three (or more) people:

```
Person A: {height: 1, weight: 2, type: 1}

Person B: {height: 1, weight: 2, type: 5}

Person C: {weight: 2, type: 1}
```

I'm trying find a distance measure that helps decide if Person A and C are more similar to each other or if Person A and B are.

If we had categorical data, I would use the Jaccard distance, but now I am trying to include the scalar values in the calculation.

The key concept is that there are some pairings where the characteristic set is incomplete and I would like to know if there is any distance scoring algorithm that handles that elegantly.

**PS** I'm not really sure how to ask this question and quite new at this, so please feel free to ask me to edit / rephrase rather than closing the question if it's not up to community standards.

Comment: I would be careful using distance measures when the dimensions have vastly different distributions. Let's say height and weight are nearly Gaussian, and type is Poisson.

Comment: When you have different types of variables (continuous, ordinal, categorical), the default distance is Gower's distance, see [this pdf](https://stat.ethz.ch/education/semesters/ss2012/ams/slides/v4.2.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

I would use [Mahalonobis distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance). When the variable is missing, simply skip it when constructing the covariance matrix and the distance itself.

Comment: For people reading this in the future, here is a link to its implementation in Python. http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.mahalanobis.html

Comment: Check that it handles missing data the way you expect.

Comment: I'll run some tests on it later, thanks a lot for the quick answer!